# putting text in front of one object and behind another object at the same time in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, layers, object-styles

I want to have one part of the text on the white triangle with it looking like it is disappearing behind the image behind the white triangle. How do I make the text appear on top of the white triangle and then behind the rest of the image at the same time? I am working in Illustrator. Image below. [image]

UPDATE:
Objects in the image are interfering with the clipping mask and arranging the layers does not seem to work.
[image]

Comment: Just a comment, but to me the white text is ON TOP of the shaded text. Am I weird?

Comment: ...by the way, unless you want to go insane, that's just going to be two placed images.

Comment: the code text is on top of the shaded area of the image, but I want the code text to go under the grey, but on top of the white. To give it the illusion of the code continuing into the grey part of the image, but not show it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perhaps you could select the white triangle, copy it and `Paste in Front` (CTRL+F). Select both text and white triangle, then `Object` > `Clipping Mask` > `Make`

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to understand your problem, but I think i've got it:

You have a white triangle on top of an image, or maybe the white triangle is part of the image? Anyway, you need to have your image contained inside a triangular shape. Construct the upper right triangle (the grey box symbolizes your image):

[image: triangle]

Now, select both the image and the triangle you just made, and choose `Object/Clipping Mask/Make`. This will transform the triangle (the uppermost object) to a mask containing your image:

[image: triangle mask]

Now you can place text behind the grey triangle:

[image: layered!]

Comment: This is definitely helpful, thank you! However, I am still having some issues. The objects on the right side of my image are drawn objects in illustrator. When I create the clipping mask the objects are covered or the objects interfere with the white triangle. Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!!! I really appreciate it. Images are in my original post for reference.

Comment: I thought by "image" you actually meant an image. But try grouping the elements that belongs to the "image" and try again. Or you could instead draw the lower left triangle and put the text inside a mask instead - that might be easier.

Comment: How do I put the text inside a mask? thank you!

Comment: Exactly the same way: Place the shape you want to use as a mask on top of the object/group you want to be contained in the mask. Select both objects and choose "Object/Clipping Mask/Make".

Comment: @beckskae welcome to the site. It seems like Wolff solved your problem. To keep the site nice and tidy and help your question to be useful for anyone who might encounter the same problem in the future, I would suggest marking it as right ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the pen tool to draw the shape of the area where you want the text to appear, then use that as a clipping mask. This is the most straightforward and easy way to do what you want, I think.

If you aren't familiar with clipping masks, [here's a tutorial you might find useful](http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/illustrator/adobe-cs5-illustrator-clipping-masks/).